# Not able to set text of textview from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity

i have main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnadd;

    int a1 = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnadd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);

        btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final SecondAct sa = new SecondAct();

                sa.ttl(a1);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

and i have other activity:

```
public class SecondAct extends Activity {

    public TextView txt2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    }

    public void numsum(int no)
    { 
        txt2.setText(String.valueOf(no));
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="addd"></Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/second"></include>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

When i click on button from main activity to set textview text of second activity then it gives me error.

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.sumdemo, PID: 13809
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException


                               at com.example.sumdemo.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can i set second activity value from main activity without passing data through `intent` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
 final SecondAct sa = new SecondAct();
 sa.ttl(a1);
```

never use the new operator on a class that extends `Activity`. You have to use `startActivity` to start `SecondAct`, and provide additional info through the `Intent` object

Comment: Is there any other solution without startactivity ?

Comment: can't i use interface for this?

Comment: No you can't. To find the views you rely on findViewById which relies on setContentView. In order to work, the Activity has to go through its lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Use Application class with a static parameter.

That is

```
class MyApp extends Application{
    public static TextView tv;
}
```

in the first activity:

```
usemyapp.tv = (TextView) findViewById(...);
```

in oreder to have an access from somewhere use this:

```
if (MyApp.tv != null)
    MyApp.tv.setText("a new text");
```

do not forget to wrap it in mainUiThread by using a handler.

in `AndroidMainfest.xml` file use this:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<this the name of the class
    >
```

Futhermore, do not create an activity class by a constructor. this is a very very bad idea:) You have this error because you have created the class but `onCreate()` method has not called and has not attached to Android UI process.

Comment: i didnt get it . can you explain in brief ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this question as guide.

[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

**And don't try to change one activity content from another activity.**

Answer (score 0):

When you create an `Activity` object through its constructor, you can't call its life cycle methods (e.g `onCreate`) so your activity doesn't have a `View` and you can't access your views. you must use `startActivity` and let android handle creating `Activity` object and call its life cycle method. you should change its view after inflating view. for your case, you can pass extra data via `Intent`s and use that data in your second `Activity`